# Fluent Validation Rule Builder Get Property Accessor

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, fluentvalidation

I'm writing an validator that works by change tracker entity state.  I'm trying to make a method to verify the entity has not been changed.

I have a validator which looks like so:

```
ConversationStateValidator : ValidatorByState<Conversation>
{
    EntityEntry CurrentEntry { get; set; }

    protected override void InitializeModifiedRules()
    {
        this.RuleFor(x => x.EmployeeUserId).Must().NotChanged(CurrentEntry );
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the expression which points to the property from the IRuleBuilder

```
static void NotChanged<T, TProperty>(IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, EntityEntry entityEntry)
{
     //I want to do something like this to get the x => x.EmployeeUserId
     ruleBuilder.GetExpectedPropertyAccessor();
}
```

Does anyone know how I can access the Expected Property Accessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this in a semi shady way.  This is relying on an implementation detail but it seems to work fine, and No reflection.

```
public static RuleBuilder<TEntity, TProp> AsRuleBuilder<TEntity, TProp>(this IRuleBuilder<TEntity, TProp> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.As<RuleBuilder<TEntity, TProp>>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using FluentValidation wrong way. Validator is some type of application service. One validator instance can validate many entities.

AbstractValidator has internal collection of validation rules and you can get PropertyRule by reflection but it is wrong way.

Comment: Yeah they shouldn’t be stateful, that’s easily fixed, I injected a singleton into them which has access to the current entry instead. There shouldn’t be anything wrong with that